# How to properly prepare Strings for SQLite insertion in Android?

Tags: android, insert, android-sqlite

So as I was learning Android, I got much advice on how to use `ContentProvider` and how to insert things correctly with that using `SqliteDatabase`. Now I have an error that makes no sense, at least with what everything everyone was telling me. The error is this:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error:
while compiling: SELECT * FROM events WHERE time_stamp='07/21/2012 2:59:03 PM' AND
event='Test This's'
```

Everything works fine as long as `'` doesn't appear anywhere. I know why because it needs to be escaped. But this doesn't make sense because everyone has been telling me to not use raw queries but rather use the provided bindings methods if that even made sense. Let me provide what my example is:

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("event_id", eventId);
newValues.put("event_name", eventName);
newValues.put("start_date", startDate);
newValues.put("start_time", values.getAsString("start_time"));
newValues.put("end_date", endDate);
newValues.put("end_time", values.getAsString("end_time"));
newValues.put("location", values.getAsString("location"));
Long success = database.insert("events_info", null, newValues);
```

From what I have been able to understand, why should I need to escape this since its suppose to bind it!? Unless this only applies to the other methods like `query()` and `update()`. In either case I am hoping someone to shed some light on the proper practice in preparing Strings for SQLite insertion in Android. Thank you in advance.

Comment: post the code for 

" //put stuff in newValues"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT * FROM events WHERE time_stamp='07/21/2012 2:59:03 PM' AND event='Test This's'

As I think you know, the date string `'07/21/2012 2:59:03 PM'` is correctly delimited, and the event string `'Test This's'` isn't.

The simple fix it change the string to `'Test This''s'`

The general problem, "how do you correct and validate input", is actually a VERY big question - involving many more issues than just "quote" delimiters.

Arguably your *best* line of defense is to use "query arguments":

```
EXAMPLE:
p_query = "select * from mytable where name_field = ?";
mDb.rawQuery(p_query, new String[] { uvalue });
```

I had a surprisingly hard time finding a good tutorial on the topic - sorry.  Here's the best I could do:

- http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Here is a good article on a related topic, "SQL Injection":

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection

Finally, if you really want to "escape" your input string, you could do worse than use a simple Java String.replaceAll ():

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: How do I escape the String? I understand this, but I thought the whole point of using the built in insert method was so I did not have to worry about that.

Comment: See thats the opposite from what I was told to do! lol. Does this fix the extra quote issue? Because wouldn't that extra quote still be there?

Comment: Haha, thats fine. I appreciate your time. The main thing I was hoping was not to have to replace every bad character for SQLite, but it looks like thats inevitable, unless I use your `rawQuery()` technique which to me seems like it makes the most sense.